# How to stop when Regex.Matches finds non-matching strings

Tags: c#, regex

I am using regex to find data in text files. I have a bunch of text files shaped like this:

```
aaa
aaa
aaa
```

My real data is more complex, but that's not what my problem is about. Now, say I have a regex that finds aaa. If I use the method Regex.Matches, I can use a foreach loop on the method's return value to get every instance of the string aaa and do something with it. But sometimes the data is not stored properly (the joys of storing data in text files):

```
aaa
bbb
aaa
```

Now, Regex.Matches will give me 2 instances of aaa to do stuff with. But because there's also bbb inside this text file, the rest of the data can't be trusted either, so I want to skip this text file.

I'm looking for a way to use a regex on this text file, and a way to detect once Regex finds characters in a string that do not match it in any way. The real regex is pretty large, so copy pasting it and saying "look for anything that doesn't match this regex" is not ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is quite broad, but the following method should work out in many cases:

`\G` is an anchor that matches at the end of the previous match, so you could use that to make sure two matches immediately follow each other. Treat it like you'd use `^` in line-by-line regexes, or wrap your pattern in `\G(?:`...`)`. You'll most probably have to make small adjustments (for instance if you want to ignore whitespace between matches, you could wrap the regex in `\G\s*(?:`...`)` instead).

You also need to make sure you actually read the whole input on the last match, so given the last `Match` object, check that its `Index + Length` matches the input length +/- any ignored content like whitespace (or solve this issue in the pattern itself, for instance by ending it with `\s*` for whitespace).

Comment: Thanks! I'm no longer at work but I'll try this tomorrow.